# ClassCastException - what to do?

Tags: android, json, classcastexception

Can anyone tell me what to do here?

I have a ClassCastException here and i have absolut no idea what to do- ive tried to research but there is not much out there. The only answer im getting is that this will happen if you cast something to something which it cannot be casted to- for instance a button to an imageview. - I hope someone can tell me what to do here.

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume starts");
    super.onResume();
    GetJsonData getJsonData = new GetJsonData((GetJsonData.OnDataAvailable) this, "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne", "en-us", true);
    getJsonData.execute("android,nougat");
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume ends");
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.examand1.Json.SpaceGalleryActivity cannot be cast to com.example.examand1.Json.GetJsonData$OnDataAvailable
    at com.example.examand1.Json.SpaceGalleryActivity.onResume(SpaceGalleryActivity.java:43)
```

Comment: What does `SpaceGalleryActivity` look like? Does it implement (or extend) `GetJsonData.OnDataAvailable`? You are required to pass an object of the second type, but you pass in your `SpaceGalleryActivity`.

Comment: Ahh - I just changed it to implement the interface OnDataAvailable - was that the right solution? I am not getting the exception anymore?

Comment: That's certainly a reasonable solution.